React best practice for useCallback when working with states & refs
I think I'm missing something in the documentation or somewhere else about useCallbacks because all documentation points towards using a state in the dependency Array. Is this really true? If yes why shouldn't i use a ref in a useCallback?
https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback
writes:

You need to pass two things to useCallback:

A function definition that you want to cache between re-renders.
A list of dependencies including every value within your component that’s used inside your function.


At least from a "documentation / knowing whats in use" standpoint i understand this but from a performance standpoint this could result in a lot of unnecessary rerenders so am i missing something?
Assuming i have the following dummy component:
function SomeComponent() {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    const increment = useCallback(() => setNumber(number + 1), [number]);
    return <CostlyComponentToRender onClick={increment}>Increment</CostlyComponentToRender >
}

With this approach I would change the increment pointer on every number change, resulting in a rerender of the costly component and potentially further children.
Also I know that in the example 1 I could write useCallback(() => setNumber(p => p + 1), []) to achieve the same effect, though only for this example not my actual usecase
Feeling smart-ish I created a small custom hook
export default function useRefState<T>(initialValue: T | null): { state: T | null, setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>, ref: MutableRefObject<T> } {
    const [state, setState] = useState<T | any>(initialValue);
    const ref = useRef(state);
    useEffect(() => { ref.current = state }, [state]); // or ref.current=state better because of missing overhead?
    return { state, setState, ref };
}

so i could basically do
function SomeComponent() {
    const {set,ref} = useRefState(0);
    const increment = useCallback(() => set(ref.current + 1), []);
    return <CostlyComponentToRender onClick={increment}>Increment</CostlyComponentToRender >
}

Now the pointer for the function "never" changes, the subcomponent doesn't need to be rerendered, the overhead feels small compared to the benefit.

Detailed example:
I have a parent and a child. The child has the button to click run, the parent has the states.
const [macroType, setMacroType] = useState(MacroType.QUEUE);
const [selectedMacro, setSelectedMacro] = useState(/*some obj*/);
const onClickRun = useCallback(() => {
    switch (macroType) {
        case MacroType.QUEUE:
            prepareMacroExecution(selectedMacro);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown macro type");
    }
}, [macroType, selectedMacro]);

This is the version i would create with the react documentation at hand. Independent of the actual child (meaning memoized or not) it needs to be rerenderd if the pointer changes, at least to replace the pointer in the child.
Applying the ref logic:
const {state:macroType, setState:setMacroType, ref:macroTypeRef} = useRefState(MacroType.QUEUE);
const {state:selectedMacro, setState:setSelectedMacro, ref:selectedMacroRef} = useRefState(/*some obj*/);
const onClickRun = useCallback(() => {
    const type = macroTypeRef.current.value;
    switch (type) {
        case MacroType.QUEUE:
            prepareMacroExecution(selectedMacroRef.current);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown macro type");
    }
}, []);

Now the function pointer doesn't change, the child doesn't need to be rerendered and the result is the same (at least to my knowledge, I'm asking if I'm missing something)

After working with the change I couldn't find any drawbacks so it will probably come down to a decision between overhead for the ref structure vs the subcomponent rendering.

In your first example, you will have an infinite loop. No need to access the number directly when setting. The setNumber function takes a callback with the current value.

@Mr.Polywhirl are you sure? I'm using a callback not an effect, the callback isn't executed directly only on demand (which would be a click event somewhere)

It would be easier and more performant to set the function and use the state's previous value like so: const increment = useCallback(() => setNumber(prevNumber => prevNumber+ 1), []);, it doesn't re-create increment each time number is changed

@Harrison very true, I am aware of this approach and noted it at the end of the question. I am asking about the theory behind it

Additionally, there is nothing against using a ref in a useCallback, but for something that is being saved in state it becomes a little superfluous. If a component is costly to render, it's worth making sure that you are memoising the props going into it, and the results of objects inside the costly component

Sorry for the answer, did not notice the ending paragraph. So the answer ends up to the classic "it depends".

To my understanding useCallback is a memoisation of the pointer though not generated through useMemo. That's why i want to optimize the memoization to "never" need a new reference

You could memoize the CostlyComponentToRender, and fix the useCallback by calling the state setter method with the current value callback and removing the dependencies.


const { memo, useCallback, useState, StrictMode } = React;

const CostlyComponentToRender = memo(({ children, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Costly Component</h2>
      <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>
    </div>
  );
});

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = useCallback(() => setCount(currCount => currCount + 1), []);
  return (
    <CostlyComponentToRender onClick={increment}>
      Increment ({count})
    </CostlyComponentToRender>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SomeComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



Note: In React 19+, you will not need to worry about memoizing and wrapping functions in callbacks. The compiler will take care of that for you.

Very much looking forward to React 19+ then :)
